# Can't Import Tensorflow in python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I cannot import Tensorflow. My gpu nvidia 940mx and I am using python 3.6.

My installed packages are :
absl-py (0.2.0)
astor (0.6.2)
bleach (1.5.0)
cycler (0.10.0)
gast (0.2.0)
grpcio (1.11.0)
html5lib (0.9999999)
kiwisolver (1.0.1)
Markdown (2.6.11)
matplotlib (2.2.2)
numpy (1.14.2)
opencv-python (3.4.0.12)
pip (9.0.3)
protobuf (3.5.2.post1)
pyparsing (2.2.0)
python-dateutil (2.7.2)
pytz (2018.4)
setuptools (39.0.1)
six (1.11.0)
tensorboard (1.7.0)
tensorflow-gpu (1.7.0)
termcolor (1.1.0)
Werkzeug (0.14.1)
wheel (0.31.0)

The error is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 75, in preload_check
        ctypes.WinDLL(build_info.cudart_dll_name)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
        self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 30, in <module>
    self_check.preload_check()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 82, in preload_check
    % (build_info.cudart_dll_name, build_info.cuda_version_number))
ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_90.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Download and install CUDA 9.0 from this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 2):

The version of Tensorflow you have installed requires CUDA 9.0. You should check if you have it installed (and not another version).

If you want to use e.g. CUDA 9.1, you would need to compile Tensorflow yourself (tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources)).

Comment: Thankyou very much and Solved the problem.. I installed the program.

Comment: If you consider this answers your question, please mark it as answered.